# How to create a select list with dynamic options, populated using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file for the model as key and its part number as value.

```
{
  "Abc": {
    "1234":"1234",
    "5678":"5678",
  },
  "Def": {
    "9101":"9101"
  }
}
```

The model value is passed in the url. I need to find the values related to the model and then display it in a dropdown using jquery dynamic options. I have looked around for days now and havent found any good examples related to this. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by _jquery dynamic options_? Which _model_? What should be _value_, _text content_ of the option elements? Very vague question, voting to close as _not a real question_.

Comment: @undefined Probably a select list with dynamic options, populated using jQuery.  Though I agree - vague at best

Comment: @undefined Sorry about the vague question. This is my first time in stack overflow. A select list with dynamic options, populated with jQuery sums it up. Model in this case will be Abc and Def. 1234, 5678 and 9101 are the values. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still a little vague but I'll try to answer based on my understanding.

So you already have your json data right?

So then you need to loop through that;

```
$.each(data, function(index, optionData) { } );
```

Then in the loop;

```
var option = new Option(optionData.Text, optionData.Value);
```

Then you could do a check for msie;

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
```

For IE you need to use;

```
dropdownList.add(option);
```

Else

```
dropdownList.add(option, null);
```

Putting it all together would allow you to add items to a dropdown from your json object.

I hope this help as your question is rather vague.